# Offset till last row in a different worksheet vba

Tags: vba, loops, excel

i am working with two worksheets **"Start sheet"** and **"Acurred Expenses"** Column A4 to lastrow has **dates in the start sheet**. I am trying to populate the dates into the Acurred expenses sheets, from **"B7"**. I am using an **offset** so the first date populated will be from A5 (Start sheet). Here is my code:

```
Sub offset_Dates()

    Dim RCount As Integer   Dim n As Integer
    Sheets("start page").Activate
    RCount = Range(Range("A5000").End(xlUp), Range("A4")).Rows.Count

        For n = 1 To RCount
            Sheets("Acurred Expenses").Activate
            Range("B7") = Sheets("start page").Range("A4").Offset(1, 0)

        Next n 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increment the range with the for loop count, so it will populate the Acurred cells with the next on the Start Page.

```
    For n = 1 To RCount
        Sheets("Acurred Expenses").Activate
        Range("B" & 6 + n) = Sheets("Start Page").Range("A" & 4 + n)
    Next n
```

This should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

You need variable in offset:

```
Range("B7").Offset(n - 1, 0) = Sheets("start page").Range("A4").Offset(n, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

also one additional variant from my side

```
Sub offset_Dates()
    Dim RCount%, cl As Range
    RCount = Sheets("start page").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cl In Sheets("start page").Range("A4:A" & RCount)
        Sheets("Acurred Expenses").Cells(cl.Row + 3, "B").Value = CDate(cl.Value)
    Next cl
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like you to consider not using `.Activate` or `.Select` methods unless you really have to (which is almost never). Active components can be very unreliable and in larger projects using them can hurt code performance. The proper way would be using variables to store pointers to your `Worksheets`, with added `Workbook` variable for being extra secure.

```
Sub offset_Dates()

    Dim RCount As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsStart As Worksheet
    Dim wsExpenses As Worksheet

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsStart = wb.Worksheets("start page")
    Set wsExpenses = wb.Worksheets("Acurred Expenses")

    RCount = Range(wsStart.Range("A5000").End(xlUp), wsStart.Range("A4")).Rows.Count

    For n = 1 To RCount
        wsExpenses.Range("B7").Offset(n - 1, 0) = wsStart.Range("A4").Offset(n, 0)
    Next n

End Sub
```